# Ideals of inductive limit of $C^{\ast}-$ algebra.

Tags: c-star-algebras, limits-colimits

I am trying to understand ideals of direct limits in the category of $C^{\ast}$-algebras.

> Let $(A_n,f_n)$ be a direct sequence of $C^{\ast}$-algebras and let $I$ be an ideal of direct limit  $\varinjlim A_n $. Is it true that there exists ideals $I_i$ of $A_i$ such that $I= \varinjlim I_i$

Unfortunately I could not find any reference.Any reference or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference could be Lemma III.4.1 in Davidson's C$^*$-algebras. You can simply take $I_j=I\cap A_j$.

Comment: Thank you. Does the same holds if one replaces ideals by primitive ideals(or modular ideals)?

Comment: Not sure, but I would say no. The properties of the direct limit depend heavily on the connecting maps. Like I said, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Martin, You might be interested in this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361809/primitive-ideals-of-inductive-limits-of-c-algebras?noredirect=1#comment912132_361809